# Under what measure is the SABR stochastic differential equations

Tags: stochastic-processes, risk-neutral-measure, sabr

The SABR Model is a CEV (constant elasticity of variance) Cox asset process with correlated lognormal stochastic volatility. A forward rate $F(t,T)$ to time $T$, observed at $t$, and the instantaneous volatility, $\sigma(t)$ follow the stochastic differential equations
\begin{align}
&dF(t,T)=\sigma(t)F(t,T)^\beta dW_F(t) \label{eq:true_sabr_model1} \\
&d\sigma(t)=\xi\sigma(t)dW_\sigma(t) \label{eq:true_sabr_model2}
\end{align}
where as the parameter $\rho$ represents the instantaneous correlation between the standard Brownian motions $W_F(t)$ and $W_\sigma(t)$ ($\langle dW_F(t)dW_\sigma(t)\rangle=\rho dt$).

My question is, are the Brownian motions in the SABR model under the physical measure $P$ or the risk-neutral measure $Q$? I can not find anything about it in the original paper. Can anyone help me with a reference to where it is stated explicitly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple forward rate $F_n(t) = F(t, T_n, T_{n+1})$ is a martingale under the measure $Q^{T_{n+1}}$, which means that the associated numeraire is the zero coupon bond $P(t, T_{n+1})$.

In the SABR model, the forward rate $F_n(t)$ is assumed to evolve under the associated measure $Q^{T_{n+1}}$ according to:

\begin{aligned}
dF_n(t) &= \sigma(t) \cdot F_n(t)^{\beta} \cdot dW^{Q^{T_{n+1}}}_n(t),\\
d\sigma(t) &= \xi \cdot \sigma(t) \cdot dZ^{Q^{T_{n+1}}}(t)
\end{aligned}

Please, notice the differences with your equations.

Comment: Today I learn. Could you add the references you gave to this answer?

Comment: Yes of course. A paper from the authors, [here](http://web.math.ku.dk/~rolf/SABR.pdf), in page 2, eq. (2.1.c). Damiano Brigo and Fabio Mercurio book: *Interest Rate Models - Theory and Practice*, page 508. Also, Andersen and Piterbarg book: *Interest Rate Modeling*, Lemma 4.2.3 in page 174. Thank you!

Comment: Also shown for equity options in section 1.3.1 [here](https://essay.utwente.nl/59228/1/scriptie_I_Khomasuridze.pdf?fbclid=IwAR3jWyPQFicgOqN8EYy3gvMGQImwG_pH9Cay8Pe1ViUigqoj0jkHNayYMGk)